Running SHOW MASTER STATUS on mysql
When running the SHOW MASTER STATUS; command, I get syntax error. This is super strange. I checked privileges, they are ok. The server-id and bin-log are both set and working. There is no replication ongoing. And if the problem were with privileges or some settings not set correctly, I wouldn't receive a SyntaxError.
Here is the complete command I run:
mysql> SHOW MASTER STATUS; 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MASTER STATUS' at line 1

I tried even running it as root and still I have a syntax error. Googling and searching the docs didn't help. MySQL version is 8.4.0

Please read the fine manual
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/show-master-status.html

15.7.7.24 SHOW MASTER STATUS Statement (no longer supported)
This statement is no longer supported, and has been replaced by SHOW BINARY LOG STATUS.

With MySQL server 8.4 a number of syntax changes regarding replication have been made.
The release notes mention several other related changes and deprecated syntax
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/mysql-nutshell.html#mysql-nutshell-deprecations

Replication SQL syntax.
A number of SQL statements used in MySQL Replication which were
deprecated in earlier versions of MySQL are no longer supported in
MySQL 8.4. Attempting to use any of these statements now produces a
syntax error. These statements can be divided into two groups those
relating to source servers, and those referring to replicas


Thank you very much. I somehow didn't find it

You wouldn’t see these pages  if you were browsing the 8.0 or older version of the documentation and the master slave syntax was used for a long time so you still find many references to that (now) legacy syntax
